# document.querySelectorAll() в IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Есть возможность заставить работать document.querySelectorAll('.myClass') в IE8? 
Ругается метод не найден, в спецификациях вроде поддержка ie 8 частично есть.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <META content="text/html; charset=Windows-1251" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
 ...
```

Comment: А что за код вы приложили к вопросу?)

Comment: @ThisMan, для уточнения какая мета указана. Думал может здесь где подвох.

Comment: используйте полифил, да не парьтесь)

Comment: @ThisMan, самому ваять или готовый где есть?

Comment: https://github.com/mtsyganov/queryselector-polyfill/blob/master/index.js например

Comment: @ThisMan, спасибо